# Which city in Burgundy is it on this Samsung ad?

Tags: france, identify-this, burgundy

I saw this ad recently on the back of a Korean newspaper

[image: Samsung Galaxy S9 Burgundy Red ad on Korean newspaper]

**What is the city featured on this ad?**

I would love to visit there during a stay in France.

The main cities in Burgundy are :

- Dijon
- Auxerre
- Macon
- Chalon sur Saone
- Nevers

I am certain it is neither Auxerre nor Dijon. But I cannot recognize the city using Google Images. Any idea?

Comment: Burgundy is employed here to describe the color of the smartphone. Went to Chalon 2 weeks ago and find it very pretty, though.

Comment: @YCR funny thing is that in French, the color burgundy is translated to "Bordeaux" , which is another famous region for wines, besides "Burgundy" the region :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. Really? I never knew. How confusing! Although, come to think of it, we also use the word 'Claret' to mean both the colour burgundy and wine from Bordeaux! If you google the phrase 'claret colour' (from an English machine anyway), the first entry is the Wikipedia article "red - Burgundy. Burgundy is a red..."

Comment: @LaurentS. French is not the only language where the colour is "bordeaux" or "bordó".

Comment: After seeing it's Budapest, I'm a little surprised/disappointed in the Ad agency. They missed a really neat opportunity, had they only followed @Taladris' thinking!

Comment: @LaurentS. I have never heard "Bordeaux" being used for the translation of "Burgundy". I've always heard(and I learned) "Bourgogne" for "Burgundy".

Comment: @Rosme "Bourgogne" is the translation of the name of the region. "Bordeaux" is the translation of the name of the color ([apparently in Quebec French](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bourgogne/10910383) "Bourgogne" is used also for the color, but it might be an English influence)

Comment: @DenisNardin and that might be exactly why to me this sounded quite weird to me(being that I am in Quebec). Well today I learn. Thanks for this explanation.

Comment: @Rosme Ah I hadn't thought of looking at your profile. Sorry!

Comment: @YCR Though the phrasing is very confusing to a native speaker. We'd always call the colour just "burgundy", so saying "Burgundy Red" does quite strongly suggest "red in the Burgundy region" rather than the redundant "red red".

Comment: @DavidRicherby oh, right. I guess only option remaining for that ad to make sense is for "Bourguignons" to invade Hungary, then :)

Comment: @YCR No, I think you're absolutely right that they do mean "red red", even though it's redundant. The text would have been written by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @David Burgundy refers to a specific shade of red, so there are sentences where red and burgundy together make sense. The oxford dictionary interestingly enough has the following example: "As summer turns into autumn, colour in your garden can be transformed into a sea of amber, orange, *red and burgundy*, if you choose the right plants". Not really working in this case though I think ("deep red red"?)

Comment: @Voo I agree that "burgundy and red" makes sense, since "red" by default is a bright red, so this is basically saying "deep red and bright red". But, as you say, "burgundy red" = "deep red red" doesn't work.

Comment: It may also be a pun. Burgundy red as "red wine from Burgundy".

Comment: @LaurentS. in Vietnamese we also call that red "Bordeaux"

Comment: @DavidRicherby Eh, adding a specific shade as a qualifying adjective modifying a more general color isn’t that unusual. What kind of red is it? A burgundy red. I’ve heard that phrasing before, with burgundy even I’m fairly sure. Also compare “emerald green,” both in that “emerald” could just be a color, making “green” somewhat redundant, and in that both emerald and burgundy, as colors, are named for things that have that color (the gemstone and the wine, in this case).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It only makes sense as a pun if the sunset is in the region of Burgundy. Hence the question.

Comment: @KRyan It looks like this may be a US/UK thing. [Google Ngrams](https://tinyurl.com/yc79babn) thinks that "emerald color" is now about twice as common as "emerald green color", whereas "emerald" is only slightly ahead with British spelling; "emerald green" was distinctly more common, historically, in both cases. However, the [equivalent for burgundy](https://tinyurl.com/y7vtszs6) puts "burgundy" overwhelmingly ahead of "burgundy red" in both dialects. (Both links are to `books.google.com/ngrams/...` but I had to use a shortener because they're 300 characters each.)

Comment: The main city in Burgundy is Beaune, the rest are a joke.

Comment: @LaurentS. , weird, I have never, ever heard that.

Comment: The comments about "burgundy red" being a redundant phrase, etc, are wholly bizarre.  It's utterly commonplace (particularly in marketing) to describe a red as burgundy red, this red, that red - even if it's redundant.  You can instantly google a zillion examples  https://www.homedepot.com/b/Doors-Windows-Exterior-Shutters/Burgundy-Red

Comment: (As a curiosity, Samsung's "burgundy red" shade is absolutely NOT, actually, what most art directors / printers / color professionals would call burgundy red!   (You can easily google, say, "Pantone burgundy red" for a somewhat "standard" interpretation of what has traditionally been called "burgundy red" (Say, 19-1617).)

Comment: @Fattie: "The main city in Burgundy is Beaune, the rest are a joke." That's completely wrong

Comment: @Taladris , it's local humor  :)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

That is the famous French city of ... [Budapest](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=budapest&tbs=isz:lt,islt:4mp,sur:fmc).

Comment: Ha ha. I was pretty sure it was not in Burgundy. But although I visited it a decade ago, I couldn't recognize Budapest. (For the sake of completion of the answer, maybe you should add a picture of Budapest or a link to Google Images as a reference for your answer)

Comment: -1 While pithy, this answer doesn’t explain how you arrived at this conclusion. The answers that show an alternate picture are much better for that. It’s also a link-only answer, so if all of a sudden the search results change (maybe a movie comes out with that name and we start seeing lots of movie posters), then it is less valuable.

Comment: @Thunderforge It answers the question, it's valid without the link and even the OP accepted it. I don't think that there is a problem with it.

Comment: "French city"? What?

Comment: @insidesin It's a joke. Re-read the question. OP assumed the 'burgundy' in the advert was a pun, so the city must have been in the Burgundy region of France. They were humorously mistaken.

Comment: You should add italics. If I came here for the city in the picture, I wouldn't be looking for jokes and your answer would be wrong.

Answer (score 79):

The city is not in France. The picture is of the river Danube in Budapest, Hungary.

[image]

Answer (score 50):

To expand other answers: judging from the angle ([Chain Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_Bridge_(Budapest))'s east pillar appearing exactly below [Margaret Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Bridge)'s middle pillar on [Margaret Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Island)), the picture was most probably taken from the [Gellért Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell%C3%A9rt_Hill) in Budapest, at about this point:

[image]

(Street view link to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.487378,19.0459767,3a,31.7y,292.85h,86.92t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sgnpVC9XQrjSIk7_jjuEUpw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) or [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/@47.48741286,19.0458928,223.95449009a,0d,60y,302.6088846h,83.14267873t,0r/data=IhoKFjFDX3VsSjNiSlBrMWtpWVdJOTVvX1EQAg)).

I believe either they edited the railing in later, or the place has been restored since Google pictured it. It has been a while since I've been there, so unfortunately I don't quite remember.

Comment: Is the guy sitting on the bench this Donald Trump guy?

Comment: @UweKeim: assuming he mistook Hungary for Slovenia and decided to visit his in-laws, it could be him ;)

Comment: @UweKeim Ahah, I was thinking about the same joke. :P

Comment: There’s a somewhat-distinctive railing in the foreground of the ad, which is a little fancier than the one we have here. The angle also seems to be a somewhat higher elevation, and maybe more to the right... actually, I sort of suspect that they took the photo with a drone or something and then super-imposed the foreground over that.

Comment: @KRyan It's possible, I dunno. Not much higher, that's sure - there's approximately one "chainbridge-pillar" space of Danube between the Margaret and Chain Bridge in both picture. Maybe they just climbed the Citadel (turn around in Street View to see the wall). But it's not that important after all... :)

Comment: I agree, the railing is most probably edited - what makes me unsure is there are some millenial-era (1900-ish) railings on the hill with a somewhat resembling shape, so if the place was indeed restored, this railing would be a reasonable choice. But I doubt the ad agency would actually get down to Budapest for a single photo, so... yeah.

Comment: @UweKeim: I was thinking the same. But Donald Trump showing his back to a camera, impossible